# set index for row grouping in data tables

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, datatables

i have two tables one is em table another is branch table. by combining these tables i need to generate datatables

```
emp table          branch table
A                   1
B                   1
C                   1
D                   2
E                   2
F                   2
G                   3
H                   3
```

i need a output in data table below format

```
India
1   1   A
2   2   B
3   3   C
Singapore
4   1   D
5   2   E
```

serverprocessing code in php

```
<?php
include_once("../../../../php/includes/dbconnection.php");

//SESSION START
session_start();

if (!isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
    header("location:../../../index.php");
}

//MYSQL CONNECTION
$dbcon = GetDbcon();
$sql_details = GetDbconArray();
$table = 'vepl_employee';
$primaryKey = 'id';

$columns = array(
    array('db' => 'D.branchName', 'dt' => '', 'field' => 'branchName'),
    array('db' => 'A.engrCode', 'dt' => 1, 'field' => 'engrCode'),
    array('db' => 'A.engrName', 'dt' => 2, 'field' => 'engrName',
            'formatter' => function( $d, $row ) {
            $tooltip = $d;
                        if (strlen($d) > 15)
                            $d = substr($d, 0, 15) . '...';
                        else
                            $d = $d;                             
                            return '<a title="'.$tooltip.'">'.$d.'</a>';
                    }
        ),
    array('db' => 'D.branchName', 'dt' => 3, 'field' => 'branchName'),
    array('db' => 'D.branchLocation', 'dt' => 4, 'field' => 'branchLocation'),
    array('db' => 'A.internationalMobile', 'dt' => 5, 'field' => 'internationalMobile',
            'formatter' => function( $d, $row ) {
            $tooltip = $d;
                        if (strlen($d) > 15)
                            $d = substr($d, 0, 15) . '...';
                        else
                            $d = $d;                             
                            return '<a title="'.$tooltip.'">'.$d.'</a>';
                    }
        ),
    array('db' => 'A.domesticMobile', 'dt' => 6, 'field' => 'domesticMobile',
        'formatter' => function( $d, $row ) {
            $tooltip = $d;
                        if (strlen($d) > 15)
                            $d = substr($d, 0, 15) . '...';
                        else
                            $d = $d;                             
                            return '<a title="'.$tooltip.'">'.$d.'</a>';
                    }
        ),
    array('db' => 'B.project_place', 'dt' => 7, 'field' => 'project_place'),
    array('db' => 'C.client_name', 'dt' => 8, 'field' => 'client_name',
            'formatter' => function( $d, $row ) {
            $tooltip = $d;
                        if (strlen($d) > 15)
                            $d = substr($d, 0, 15) . '...';
                        else
                            $d = $d;                             
                            return '<a title="'.$tooltip.'">'.$d.'</a>';
                    }
        ),
    array('db' => 'A.employee_status', 'dt' => 9, 'field' => 'employee_status'),
    array('db' => 'A.id', 'dt' => 10, 'field' => 'id')

);

require( 'ssp.class1.php' );

$joinQuery='FROM vepl_employee AS A LEFT JOIN vepl_project AS B ON B.id=A.currentProject LEFT JOIN vepl_client AS C ON C.id=B.client_id LEFT JOIN vepl_branches AS D ON D.id=A.branchId';
$where="A.engrDesignation NOT IN('Accounts Executive','Country Manager') AND A.employee_status != 'Deputed' AND A.currentProject != 0 AND A.company=".$_SESSION['company'];
$result = SSP::simple($_GET, $sql_details, $table, $primaryKey, $columns,$joinQuery,$where);
$start = $_REQUEST['start'];
$start++;
foreach ($result['data'] as &$res) {   
   $res[0] = (string) $start;
    $start++;
}
echo json_encode(
  $result
);
?>
```

In jquery function

```
$('#emptotTable').DataTable({
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": true,
    "ajax": "includes/employeelistServer.php",
    "fnRowCallback": function (nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex) {
        $('td:eq(1)', nRow).html('<a href="view_employee.php?id=' + aData[10] + '">' + aData[1] + '</a>');
        return nRow;
    },
    "drawCallback": function () {
    var api = this.api();
    var rows = api.rows( {page:'current'} ).nodes();
    var last=null;

    api.column(4, {page:'current'} ).data().each( function ( group, i ) {
        if ( last !== group ) {
            $(rows).eq( i ).before(
                '<tr class="group"><td colspan="10" style="color:#A21DF9;font-weight:bold;font-style: oblique;">'+group+'</td></tr>'
            );
             last = group;
        }

    } );
    }
});
```

actually i got output in that format. but i need a output above mentioned format.

```
India
1       A
2       B
3       C
Singapore
4       D
5       E
```

thanks in advance